# Modifying DE10-nano default FPGA configuration

Tags: intel-fpga

I am working with Linux software on DE10-nano board and I need to perform a small modification to default FPGA configuration (add pull-ups on GPIO lines).

The user manual points to DE10-Nano System CD\Demonstrations\FPGA\Default as default project which suppose to produce the factory FPGA configuration.

I compile it, convert SOF to RBF, and put the RBF on SD card for U-Boot to load.

U-Boot programs FPGA (I get orange LED on) and then fails to load Linux device tree (I get ERROR: Did not find a cmdline Flattened Device Tree message via COM port) although the same device tree file is in the same place on SD card.

Am I using the correct Quartus project?

Comment: Does the manual mention anything about the settings for the RBF conversion?

Comment: @PenguMC No, I just scanned all the DE10-nano pdfs to check it.

Comment: Check https://bitlog.it/20170820_building_embedded_linux_for_the_terasic_de10-nano.html - you'll find out that preloader needs to be recreated.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me (loading my own .rbf file with the unmodified Linux Angrstrom from Terasic) was to use the SD card images from:
http://download.terasic.com/downloads/cd-rom/de10-nano/linux_BSP/

I used the de10_nano_linux_console image. I used the sof_to_rbf.bat file to generate the .rbf file, ensuring that compression was turned on and the output file name was soc_system.rbf.

Any other method I tried with the SD card resulted in the error message the OP posted relating to the Device Tree.